# Reconfigure a TC Build Agent

Tags: .net, visual-studio, teamcity

I've inherited this TC install and am trying to figure it out. The build agent has been in place for over a year and it compiled most projects just fine that were configured to compile using VS2013. However we have been using VS2017 in development and I tried to changed the project settings so that it would compile under VS2017. Once I did that the project is no longer compatible with the build agent. So I figured that there is a setting in the Agent that requires a certain version of VS (2013 in this case). I have been searching for 3 days and cannot find a setting to reconfigure the Agent. So what do i do to bring the project back in compliance and have it built under VS2017? By chance I noticed the same situation when I attempted to change how the build/release number is generated. So any help on both of these would be a great help.

Looked in the buildAgent.properties file but nothings jumps out as a setting.

Comment: You need the 2017 build tools installed on that agent.

Comment: If you can add the specific error message when you try to compile, it will be easier to figure out the missing feature(s).

Comment: @DidierAupest It won't get to the compile step. The build job won't run because no compatible build agents are available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install visual studio 2017 onto the server running the build agent. I believe the community edition world suffice.  That will install everything necessary to compile. You'll need to restart the build agent windows service as well.

Comment: Only the build tools need to be installed.  A complete installation of VS is not necessary.  The build tools can be downloaded separately.

Comment: @amy I've never had it actually compile anything but class libraries with just the build tools.  Something is always missing and a vs install adds whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions and based on them I installed VS 2017 on the TC Server and it worked just fine. My projects are now compliant and build.